# Multiple conditions using 'or' in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

So I have these conditions:

> A = 0 to 10 **OR** 40 to 60
>
> B = 20 to 50

and I have this code:

```
area1 = N.where((A>0) & (A<10)),1,0)
area2 = N.where((B>20) & (B<50)),1,0)
```

My question is: how do I do '**OR**' condition in numpy?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If numpy overloads `&` for boolean `and` you can safely assume that `|` is boolean `or`.

```
area1 = N.where(((A>0) & (A<10)) | ((A>40) & (A<60))),1,0)
```

Comment: I think that `&` is bitwise and...which (in this case) is irrelevant since (A>0) is an array of `True`/`False` (i.e. `1`s and `0`s)

Comment: One gotcha is to not forget to put the inequalities in parentheses because of their lower operation priority.

Answer (score 32):

There's `numpy.logical_or`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html

numpy `logical_and` and `logical_or` are the ufuncs that you want (I think)

Note that `&` is not `logical and`, it is **bitwise** `and`.  This still works for you because (a>10) returns a logical array (e.g. 1's and 0's) as does your second condition.  So, in this case, "logical and" and "bitwise and" are equivalent (same with logical and bitwise `or`).  But in other cases, the bitwise operations may yield surprising results (mostly because python's `&` and `|` operators have lower precedence than expected in these contexts).