# How does R treat positional arguments

Tags: r, arguments

I'm a python guy and very new to R (so far, all I've done is copy-paste code and screen-shot the resulting, graph).

I would now like to actually learn the language so that I can draw useful plots (right now, I am trying to plot [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19578185/198633)).

In attempting my first plot, I came across this function call:

```
sets_options("universe", seq(from = 0, to = 25, by = 0.1))
```

Now, I would like to know if I can achieve the same result by calling

```
sets_options("universe", seq(0, 25, 0.1))
```

The help page for `seq` doesn't speak to this specifically (or I'm not reading it correctly), so I was hoping someone could shed some light on how R handles positional arguments

I tried calling the function that way in R and it worked (no syntax errors, etc), but I don't know how to test the output of that function, so I'm forced to ask here

Comment: The full details of how arguments are matched: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching. Roughly, named arguments are matched first, then the remaining (passed) arguments are matched to the remaining (formal) arguments positionally.

Comment: Some comments on when to use named vs. position at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#calling-functions

Answer (score 0):

Calling `sets_options()` will display the current settings. From the following log, it seems that the positional arguments are treated as expected:

```
> sets_options("universe", seq(0,5,0.25))
> sets_options()
$quote
[1] TRUE

$hash
[1] TRUE

$openbounds
[1] "()"

$universe
 [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00 2.25 2.50 2.75 3.00 3.25 3.50 3.75 4.00 4.25 4.50 4.75 5.00

> sets_options("universe", seq(from=0,to=5,by=0.25))
> sets_options()
$quote
[1] TRUE

$hash
[1] TRUE

$openbounds
[1] "()"

$universe
 [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00 2.25 2.50 2.75 3.00 3.25 3.50 3.75 4.00 4.25 4.50 4.75 5.00
```

Comment: Correct. Positional arguments are always valid in R and the order that is present in python is not in R.  You can also define your function args in whatever order you want.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what seq is doing with positional versus named objects. The way to address this looking at the ?seq page which lays out the named arguments and their order:

```
seq(from = 1, to = 1, by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1)),
length.out = NULL, along.with = NULL, ...)
```

So `seq(0, 25, 0.1)` will be interpreted the same way as `seq(from = 0, to = 25, by = 0.1)` since the order is the same as name in Usage listing.

Comment: I did read that page and try to arrive at the conclusion you propose. However, I noticed that `by` defaults to `((to - from)/(length.out - 1))`, and `length.out` defaults to `NULL`. So, I couldn't be as sure about what variables take on what values, since one of the default assignments uses a value I don't supply

Comment: Your values replace the defaults.

Comment: But what if I don't supply a value for `((to - from)/(length.out - 1))`?

Comment: Then `by` gets calculated using that expression based on what is given to `from`, `to` and `length.out`

Comment: But I still haven't specified `length.out`, which defaults to `NULL`.

Comment: I guess you need to refer to the ultimate arbiter, the code for `seq.default`.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea. Thanks