# Using np.piecewise for a uniform distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot the following cumulative distribution function

[image]

and to do this I thought I could use `np.piecewise` as follows

```
x = np.linspace(3, 9, 100)
np.piecewise(x, [x < 3, 3 <= x <= 9, x > 9], [0, float((x - 3)) / (9 - 3), 1])
```

but this gives the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) is a capricious beast.

Use :

```
x = np.linspace(3, 9, 100)
cond = [x < 3, (3 <= x) & (x <= 9), x > 9];
func = [0, lambda x : (x - 3) / (9 - 3), 1];
np.piecewise(x, cond, func)
```

Explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578185/multiple-pieces-in-a-numpy-piecewise).