# Positional Arguments in numpy.piecewise()

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I am trying to create a piecewise function using numpy, and I followed the examples in its documentation, however, only the outer bounds return the correct values.

The function I have for the `44 < x < 58` returns 0, while it should return the value calculated in the cell below. I'm sure this is a simple syntax error, but I am having trouble seeing it.

```
x = 50
numpy.piecewise(x, [(44 < x) & (x < 58), x <= 44, x >= 58], [(0.4876 +0.1201*math.cos(x*1.017) + 0.5111*math.sin(x*1.1017)), 0, 1])
```

Edit: I updated the syntax of the boolean and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please insert code as text and not as an image.

Comment: `a < x < b` does not work for numpy.  Use `(a < x) | (x < b)`.

Comment: @FrankYellin I assume you mean `&` not `|`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Pieces in a numpy.piecewise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578185/multiple-pieces-in-a-numpy-piecewise)

Comment: piecewise returns an array of the SAME TYPE as x; x being an int, it returns an int... Try with x = 50.0

Comment: Also, if you're using numpy, use `np.sin` and `np.cos` rather than the math library's functions. The numpy versions can work with numpy arrays.