# Comparing a numpy array object to multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to use `numpy.where` to find the indices I want. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([20,58,32,0,107,57]).reshape(2,3)
item_index = np.where((a == 58) | (a == 107) | (a == 20))
print item_index
```

I get `item_index` as below:

```
(array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]))
```

However, in reality, the dimensions of `a` is `20000 x 7` and the conditions are several hundred instead of just three. Is there a way to use `numpy.where` for multiple conditions? I found topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377096/multiple-conditions-using-or-in-numpy-array), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030480/numpy-array-how-to-select-indices-satisfying-multiple-conditions) useful, but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

Comment: I'd say the problem you're having isn't connected to `where`. The problem you're having is efficiently compressing several hundred equality conditions into one short, efficient condition.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree. I will likely to edit the title. In the solutions provided other users did not use `where` at all and mostly used `np.in1d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given (per your example):

```
>>> a
array([[ 20,  58,  32],
       [  0, 107,  57]])
```

with the query, 'is an array element of a in a list of values', just use [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.in1d(a, [58, 107, 20])
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you want the indexes to be the same as the underlying array, just reshape to the shape of `a`:

```
>>> np.in1d(a, [58, 107, 20]).reshape(a.shape)
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then test against that:

```
>>> tests=np.in1d(a, [58, 107, 20]).reshape(a.shape)
>>> tests[1,1]                 # is the element of 'a' in the list [58, 107, 20]?
True
```

In one line (obvious, but I do not know if efficient for one off queries):

```
>>> np.in1d(a, [58, 107, 20]).reshape(a.shape)[1,1]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone better at numpy may have a better solution - but if you have [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) installed you could do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a) # Create a pandas dataframe from array

conditions = [58, 107, 20]
item_index = df.isin(conditions).values.nonzero()
```

`isin` builds boolean array which is True is the value is in the `conditions` list.  The call to `.values` extracts the underlying numpy array from the pandas DataFrame.  The call to `nonzero()` converts bools to 1s and 0s.

Comment: The same can be achieved in numpy alone using `np.in1d` and some magic with the indexing: `np.unravel_index(np.in1d(a, [58, 107, 20]).nonzero()[0], a.shape)`

Comment: @chrisb I'm thinking to use `pandas` at some point and your solution would totally work using pandas.

Comment: @Jaime Solutions similar to your were provided by two other members. I tested it and it totally works.

Answer (score 2):

Add another dimension to each so they can be broadcast against each other:

```
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([20,58,32,0,107,57]).reshape(2,3)
>>> b = np.array([58, 107, 20])
>>> np.any(a[...,np.newaxis] == b[np.newaxis, ...], axis = 2)
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```