# Numpy: indexing on one dimensional arrays with a condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have to index an x and a y axis with a condition on an x axis.
I tried using the np.where function like this:

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
y = y[np.where((x < 111) or (x > 125))]
x = x[np.where((x < 111) or (x > 125))]
```

But it prints the following error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried using np.all then like this:

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
y = y[np.all([(x < 111) or (x > 125)], axis = 0)]
x = x[np.all([(x < 111) or (x > 125)], axis = 0)]
```

But got the same error, am I doing the 'or' condition wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worth having a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10377096/12063126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays use the numpy `logical` methods, standard python conditionals `and` and `or` don't work well.

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
y = y[np.logical_or((x < 111), (x > 125))]
x = x[np.logical_or((x < 111), (x > 125))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bitwise operator instead of `or` i.e `|`

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
y = y[np.where((x < 111) | (x > 125))]
x = x[np.where((x < 111) | (x > 125))]
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

# test data
x = np.arange(0, 200)

# conditions:
# values wanted that are smaller than 111 and bigger than 125
cond1 = 111 > x
cond2 = x > 125

# get data that satisfies both conditions
x *= np.logical_or(cond1, cond2)

# (optional) remove zeros
x = x.nonzero()
```